# How to show menu items on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bottom navigation bar. I just want to show menu items on hover on each navigation button. Is that possible to do with bootstrap?

Comment: So how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? If not I suggest you do your homework and ask the actual **difficulty** that arises.

Comment: Take a look into http://bootsnipp.com/search?q=navbar you get loads of stuffs that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
<div class="mainmenu">          
<ul>            
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">About us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>                
</ul>
</div>​
```

Style :

```
.submenu ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 0px;
}​
.submenu:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code

HTML

```
<div class="mainmenu">          
<ul>            
    <li><a href="home.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><a>ABOUT US</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>SOFTWARE TEAM</a></li>
            <li><a>EPUB TEAM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>CAREERS</a></li>
    <li><a>CONTACT US</a></li>                
</ul>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.submenu:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.submenu ul {
    top: 40px;
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}​
```